# Change UI Elements by threads in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-linearlayout

How do i change the background of a LinearLayout via setBackgroundColor() by another thread?

I learned, that the Android UI Framework is not threadsafe, so you can't change UI elements by another Thread than the UI thread.

My goal is to create a strobe light effect by calling the setBackgroundColor() method with changing colors (in this case black/white/black/ect,) on a LinearLayout which fills the entire screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use  `Handler` with message queues.  You instantiate the `Handler` in the main UI thread, then use `obtainMessage()` to send messages to the `Handler`.  So an example would be like

```
public final Handler updateTextView = new Handler(){
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg)
   {
      if(msg.what == UPDATE_TEXT){
          myTextView.setText("arg1 = " + msg.arg1 +
                             "; arg2 = " + msg.arg2 + "; " + (String)msg.obj);
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your thread you can call:

```
String myString = new String("test");
updateTextView.obtainMessage(UPDATE_TEXT, 10, 20, myString).sendToTarget();
```

The result if called once will be `myTextView` now says "arg1 = 10; arg2 = 20; test".

Answer (score 0):

Read blogpost about [painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html). Basically changes in UI must happen on UI thread. Article describes a few ways to achieve that. IMO in your case it would be best to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).